# Is possible to parallelize list-comprehensions?

Tags: python, loops, parallel-processing, global-variables

I've never used a parallel library before and I'm having some trouble to implement the code in a program I've writed. First I calculate the common data for all the years and created some objects to recive the generated data for every year. Then, after generate the data for each year, I merged the data to export some files.

The concept of the code look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import someParallelLibrary

firstYear = 2010
lastYear = 2060
dfData = pd.read_csv("/data.csv") 

def dataGeneratorA(O, D, year):
    return 1, 2 #Actually filter data and calculate a lot of things...
#... 
def dataGeneratorN(O, D, year):
    return 3
    
#Objects to recive the data of each year
dataObjectA = {}
#... 
dataObjectN = {}

for year in range(firstYear,lastYear+1):
    df = dfData.copy()
    #do a lot of stuff in the dataframe here for each year then:
    processedData = [dataGeneratorA(O, D, year) for (O, D) in zip(df['O'],df['D'])]
    df['A'] = [value[0] for value in processedData]
    df['B'] = [value[1] for value in processedData]
    #... 
    df['N'] = [dataGeneratorN(O, D, year) for (O, D) in zip(df['O'],df['D'])]

    dataObjectA[year] = df[['O','D','A']].rename(columns={'A':str(year)})
    #... 
    dataObjectN[year] = df[['O','D','N']].rename(columns={'H':str(year)})

#group the data to export
for key in dataObjectA.keys():
     finalData = finalData.merge(dataObjectA[key], on =['O','D'], how = 'left' )
finalData.to_csv('./output/finalDataA.csv')
#...     
for key in dataObjectN.keys():
     finalData = finalData.merge(dataObjectN[key], on =['O','D'], how = 'left' )
finalData.to_csv('./output/finalDataN.csv')
```

First I was thinking about parallelize this inline loops that are time consuming, but I couldn't make it work with any library.

```
processedData = [dataGenerator1(O, D, year) for (O, D) in zip(df['O'],df['D'])]
```

So I was thinking about create a function to wrap the years calculation and `map` it. So I could parallelize all the `foreach year` code.

It would be more eficient and easy if I parallel the years?
If yes, what is the best way to recive the parallel data in to all `global` dictionaries?

Comment: That is not an "inline loop". That is a list-comprehension.

Comment: ok, I've changed the title. thanks

Comment: There's a `map()` operation in the `threading` module, that seems roughly equivalent.